# Get dictionary from sqlite query when using python databases module

Tags: python, sqlite

I am developing an asynchronous program and have decided to use [databases](https://pypi.org/project/databases/) module for interacting with a database. The problem is that when making queries I get a tuple as a response. However I want to receive the response in a dictionary format like this: `'column_name1': column_value1, ..., 'column_name_n': column_value_n`.
I have found some solutions but they all use sqlite3 module.

Comment: share relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import databases

pathtodb = '/path/to/your/database.db'
tablename = 'table_name_in_your_database'

database = databases.Database('sqlite:///{}'.format(pathtodb))
query1 = "PRAGMA table_info('{}')".format(tablename)
pragma = await database.fetch_all(query=query1)
query2 = "SELECT * FROM {}".format(tablename)
data = await database.fetch_all(query=query2)

dictionary_keys = list(zip(*pragma))[1]
dictionary_values = list(zip(*data))

dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary_keys,dictionary_values))
```